# Fluent NHibernate, Referencing Hard-Coded C# Method

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate

I have some functionality that needs to be 'selectable' as an option for certain objects in my database, but the actual code behind each method is far too complicated to be serialized into a database. They also cannot be SQL Stored Procedures.

So basically, I have a static `List<T>` of these functions. Is there a standard way of associating these with objects in my database? For instance..

```
var functions = new static List<Omega>{
 new Omega {
   Id = 1, // this would be useful to a database, but nothing really sets it.
   Name = "Some Name", // this isn't useful. It's a string literal
   Function = // this may be a Method, or a Lambda Expression, or something else.
 }
};

class Psi { 
  Guid Id { get; set; }
  Omega Omega { get; set; } // how can I keep a hard-reference here?
}
```

Comment: So the problem is how to persist Omega reference from Psi instance to database?

Comment: Yes. The `Omega` is far, far, far, far too complicated to serialize. But it still has to exist, and be referenced. I'd like to avoid using 'Magic strings' if possible.

Comment: And all instances of Omega are stored in a collection? Is this collection global for the application or are related to specific instance of Psi? Can the Omega's Function any parameters. If yes, how is the delegate invoked?

Comment: They are stored in a collection. How they accept parameters is not relevant. The parameters they take can be serialized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I am not sure if I got it correctly. Delegates are [serializable](http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2011/04/serializing-continuations.html) and therefore they can be stored into a database, e.g. [using NH](http://jakub-linhart.blogspot.com/2011/05/nhibernate-serializing-delegates.html). There are some limitation but serializing delegates is an adventurous journey anyway:).

If it is not a viable way, then you could try to implement all your "functions" as static methods. Class and method name can be stored in a table column and invoked via reflection.

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding how this would work. I'm not entirely sure how to wrap the method call into a delegate that can be serialized.

Comment: This is really neat, and it is very useful for some things - but it does not really solve my problem because the data in question is too complicated to be a simple serializable delegate.

Comment: If you are working with complex state in your Omega's "Function" and the "Function" represents complex algorithm then maybe something like Workflow Foundation is the true way for you. This framework is designed to solve such things. Anyway I'm curious what are you trying to achieve:).

Comment: eh, Windows Workflow is a bit overkill, and I don't have the time to learn it for this. Executing what I need is not the problem - storing it in the database is.

Comment: As for what I am trying to achieve... essentially imagine anonymous methods as selectable functions for the client. It is kind of difficult to explain without the entire scope of the project visible.

Comment: This method will actually work for me - I just have to figure out the solution to a new problem it introduced - but it's unrelated to the question. Now I have to figure out where to store things that are being accessed without a hard-coded path. But the layer this is on has no knowledge of my IoC container, so injecting that will be irritating... Thank you very much for the resources, it is very useful!